# Async/Await Seems to work synchronously in Winforms

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, .net-core, async-await

I have a piece of code as follows

```
Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Form1.Load
   Await Load_DataAsync()
End Sub

Private Function Load_DataAsync as Task(Of Boolean)
  FetchData()
  Return Task.FromResult(True)
End Function

Private Sub FetchData()
  'Connects to Db and collect the data
End Sub
```

In terms of UI responsiveness I dont see any difference between when I await the Load_DataAsync() and when I Call it without the await keyword.

I Have Tried the following

```
Await Task.Run(Function()
                  Load_DataAsync()
               End Function)
```

and the App proceeds without blocking the UI

What am I doing wrong please

Comment: There's no asynchronous code in the question. `async` doesn't make a method run in the background by itself, it's only syntactic sugar that allows using `await` to await already executing asynchronous functions

Comment: What does `FetchData` do? Instead of using `await Task.Run(FetchData)` it's better to use asynchronous DB operations like `DbConnection.OpenAsync()`, `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` to execute the operations without blocking a thread

Comment: Your `Form1_Load` is properly async as it is declared `Async` and it `Await`s something in its body.  However, your `Load_DataAsync` is not properly async as it does not `Await` anything in its body and calls `FetchData` synchronously.  Also see the previous comment on what you should be doing in `FetchData` to make it properly asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way not to block the UI is to run an operation as a task. In your case as you mentioned, `Await Task.Run(Function() Load_DataAsync())` is the correct way to do it, otherwise your `FetchData()` will run on the the calling thread. Again, though as other people commented it is recommended to use asynchronous DB operations.